# dynamic menu items from photoshop template

Tags: photoshop

I'm hoping I can get some clarification on how to correctly implement a Photoshop template into a webpage. I understand the slice and save methods. My confusion comes in when constructing the site, specifically a menu bar. I would like the menu option to change color when a visitor hovers the link. With Photoshop, everything is save as an image. How do you get the text to change color if it is an image? Do I save two images, one black and one white, then on hover have the images change with JavaScript? Can I accomplish this with CSS rather than JavaScript? How would I create a drop down menu that consists of multiple sub items? Would I need separate images for each sub item?

Hopefully, this is clear. As, you can probably see, there is a lot of confusion here. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the answer is YES. To create dynamic menus, multiple images are used. I believe Adobe calls it creating rollover images and they have a great topic @ http://adobe.ly/zTQh7E 

If you know of any other way, please let me know. As for now, I'm going to keep creating images to display through JavaScript code for rollover action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With photoshop you have a tool that allow you to divide each parts of your menu bar and automatically make several images that you will use it for your button of your menu.

Look this link to do this but it is in french (sorry for that): http://www.wks.fr/Creer-un-menu-black-gloss-decoupe.html

After you can add your images like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  >
   <tr>
         <td><a href="Default.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_01.gif" alt="" border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_01.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_01.gif'"/></a></td>
         <td><a href="Emplacements.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_02.gif" alt=""border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_02.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_02.gif'"/></a></td>
         <td><a href="Tarifs.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_03.gif" alt=""border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_03.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_03.gif'"/></a></td>
         <td><a href="Reservation.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_04.gif" alt=""border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_04.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_04.gif'"/></a></td>
         <td><a href="Galerie.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_05.gif" alt=""border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_05.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_05.gif'"/></a></td>
         <td><a href="About.aspx"><img src="images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_06.gif" alt=""border="0" onmouseover="this.src='images/imagesMenu/Menu_06.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/imagesMenu/MenuBis_06.gif'"/></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can see that for each column of the table you have one image wich will be visible when the cursor of the mouse is out of it but when the mouse is over the other image is visible.

It is a way to do what you want. There are others ways but this is easy to do.